# CakePHP 3 - order on contain data not working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0, containable

I am using CakePHP 3.x and I am trying to sort my data on containable data that I need for my paginator to be able to sort on it.

I have the following options for my paginator:

```
public function getEventSignupsOptionsForPagination($id)
{
    $options = array(
        'limit' => 30,
        'conditions' => array(
            'event_id' => $id
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'signup_date' => 'asc'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Users',
            'Events.Instances.DkpLists.DkpListEntries.Users'
        ),
        'sortWhitelist' => array(
            'Users.username',
            'Events.Instances.DkpLists.DkpListEntries.current',
            'message',
            'status',
            'signup_date'
        )
    );

    return $options;
}
```

This set of options returns the correct data. But when I try to sort on it, it gives an error.

I use the following line to sort in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('Events.Instances.DkpLists.DkpListEntries.current', 'DKP'); ?>
```

This works, untill I click on it, then I get the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Events.Instances' in 'order clause'
```

I don't understand why this is going wrong, because it can retrieve the proper data, but it can't sort on it.

Answer (score 1):

Please use like,

$this->Pages->find('all', [
'contain' => ['Rows' => [
  'conditions' => ['Rows.parent_id' => 0],
  'queryBuilder' => function ($q) {
     return $q->order(['order_number' =>'asc']);
  }
]])->toArray();